# How to search a string for a particular character or number or punctuation character

Tags: c

I know we use ctype.h for various comparisons.I can make a program where i have to check weather the given character is an UPPER CASE or LOWER CASE.
But suppose i have entered a string "Singh21$" 
then how to check that this string contains an uppercase,a dollar sign and at least a number.
If a string contains these three then say "its a strong password".

Comment: try  checking the ascii value range, A-Z  65 to 90 for  the chracters in the string.

Comment: A set of flags, a loop and the [character classification functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte).

Comment: http://webtecker.com/2008/03/26/collection-of-password-strength-scripts/ its not C, uses javascript but logic remain same ..! You would have googled it before asking

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:

```
for(int i =0; i < strlen(stringPassword); ++i)
{

    if( islower(stringPassword[i]) )
        hasLower = true;

    if( isupper(stringPassword[i]) )
        hasUpper = true;

    if( isdigit(stringPassword[i]) )
        hasDigit = true;

    if( isalnum(stringPassword[i]) )
        hasSpecial = true;
}
```

And if all the flags are true then consider it as strong password.